# Not able to see the imported module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library

I have imported the module from my previous android project but when i try to add it as a library it is not showing and it is not showing as a module I am able to see the module only in the project mode my gradle is also working fine

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

is also i am using but dont know why when i try to add module from project structure it show no module what will i do i followed many question and non is solving my problem i have every thing update and of latest version
my gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.musicplayer.music.audioplayer"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

project.gradle

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: How did you import your module ? copy/paste ? via the import module function ?

Comment: No, Files->New->ImportModule and selected the module that i wa using earlier. I am facing this since i have updated my android studio to latest version

Comment: Can you add your settings.gradle file? Maybe the module is missing there